Laptop won't start after updating and rebooting
My laptop was working very slow, so I restarted it (it asked if I want to updated and reboot, I pressed yes) After reboot it went into I initramfs mode, I used the fsck command and rebooted after that. After that the laptop won't start and is stuck here. I am very new to Ubuntu.
Ubuntu 22.04
[FAILED] Failed to start CUPS Scheduler.
[FAILED] Failed to start Power Profiles daemon.
[FAILED] Failed to start Accounts Service.
[FAILED] Failed to start Snap Daemon.
[FAILED] Failed to start Accounts Service.
[FAILED] Failed to start Snap Daemon.
[FAILED] Failed to start User Manager for UID 128.
[FAILED] Failed to start Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
[FAILED] Failed to start Snap Daemon.
[FAILED] Failed to start Time & Date Service.


I also tried to reboot in recovery mode and it's also stuck.

Welcome to AskUbuntu. If the notebook won’t successfully boot from its internal storage, you will need to use the USB installer to boot the machine. This should allow you to access the internal storage to read the logs and find out what the problem is.

Ubuntu asked you to update and reboot?

After reboot, on the pop-up it asked, update and reboot and i clicked yes.

Can you choose advanced options for Ubuntu and choose old kernel
